# What animal is this?

Tags: species-identification

I have seen this bug/worm twice on my dog's leg after taking him for a walk this week. I think that this is a leech, but my mom disagrees because she says leeches are not found where we live but are found around beaches. We live in Carmel Mountain San Diego: [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Carmel+Mountain+Ranch,+San+Diego,+CA+92128/@32.9766367,-117.0871462,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x80dbfa025e72f11d:0xaadd82acb6a410aa!8m2!3d32.9805356!4d-117.0735241).
The closest beach is around 15 minutes away.
The bug is approximately the size of a fingernail, and it did not do anything when I picked it up.

[image]

EDIT: We were just walking around my neighborhood, nowhere jungle-ish at all.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What kind of environment(s) are you walking through? There are definitely leeches in California, but leeches are typically associated with wetlands ...

Comment: I added an edit, with details about the environment of the walks.

Comment: Leeches are found other places than beaches. Some live in [streams, lakes](https://www.maine.gov/dep/water/monitoring/biomonitoring/sampling/bugs/leeches.html), [rainforests](https://www.wettropics.gov.au/site/user-assets/docs/leeches.pdf), [mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haemadipsa), and even aquatic locations [in deserts](https://www.desertusa.com/insects/leeches.html)

Comment: @theforestecologist interesting. I guess San Diego can be considered a Desert, but I do not think there are any aquatic locations around where we live.